# What is the difference between the exitExecution() and stopExecution() in Webharvest Scraper class

Tags: java, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scraper, webharvest

I want to know what is the difference between the

```
scraper.exitExecution() and 

scraper.stopExecution() and 

scraper.finishExecutingProcessor()
```

I have tried looking in to the [java doc](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/doc/org/webharvest/runtime/Scraper.html), I could not find anything over there. There seems to be no proper documentation for this. Please help.

I need a method to stop the execution of the scraper after some timeout, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just download `sourses` of the library and look inside it?

Source code analyze shows, that the difference is only in statuses which these functions are set.

`STATUS_STOPPED` is interpreted as that configuration was aborted by user. 
`STATUS_EXIT` is interpreted as configuration was just exited.

I.e. they are almost equal.

Let's do it together:

One:

```
public void exitExecution(String message) {
    setStatus(STATUS_EXIT);
    this.message = message;
}
```

Two:

```
public void stopExecution() {
    setStatus(STATUS_STOPPED);
}
```

Next, going to `BaseProcessor` class, this is one of the two places where `STATUS_EXIT` or `STATUS_STOPPED` statuses are used:

```
public Variable run(Scraper scraper, ScraperContext context) {
        int scraperStatus = scraper.getStatus();

        if (scraperStatus == Scraper.STATUS_STOPPED || scraperStatus == Scraper.STATUS_EXIT) {
            return EmptyVariable.INSTANCE;
        }
        ...
}
```

Another one in class `ConfigPanel`:

```
public void onExecutionEnd(Scraper scraper) {
...
} else if (status == Scraper.STATUS_STOPPED) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    GuiUtils.showWarningMessage("Configuration \"" + configDocument.getName() + "\" aborted by user!");
                    ide.setTabIcon(ConfigPanel.this, ResourceManager.SMALL_FINISHED_ICON);
                }
            });
        } else if ( status == Scraper.STATUS_EXIT && message != null && !"".equals(message.trim()) ) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    GuiUtils.showWarningMessage("Configuration exited: " + message);
                    ide.setTabIcon(ConfigPanel.this, ResourceManager.SMALL_FINISHED_ICON);
                }
            });
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there way of terminating the scraper so that it wont wait for too long to get the data from the webpage?